# Does Average Total Cost (ATC) include implicit opportunity costs?

Tags: microeconomics, cost, opportunity-cost

Does the average total cost include opportunity costs? If so, are these opportunity costs considered fixed costs or variable costs? How are they calculated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Generally, ATC does include implicit costs unless otherwise specified by regular accounting